# Sonarqube server setup and host url

Tags: sonarqube, sonarscanner

I am trying to integrate sonarqube to my CI/CD pipeline. I have successfully created and analysed the project by running my ci/cd pipeline locally. But now I want to be able to access it remotely for anyone to be able to run the sonarqube.

This is my script to run sonarqube in drone ci:

```
return {
    "name": "code-analysis",
    "image": "aosapps/drone-sonar-plugin:latest",
    "settings": {
       "sonar_host": "what to set here?",
       "sonar_token": "xxx",
       "usingProperties": "true"
    }
  }
```

So what can I set in sonar_host to be able to run sonarqube remotely as a server rather than just running it locally?